# Transparency animation not working with a plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials, transparency

I'm trying to create a simple animation. I have have a plane and a line, first the line fades out, then the plane fades out. For that I am using the transparency value. The line fades out just fine, but I am having problems with the plane. I set a key frame with the transparency value at 0 in the frame 260:

And then I set another key frame at the frame 320, with the transparency value at 1.

[image]

But the plane is still there, still visible, I do the same with the line and it works fine. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Could you upload a .blend using [BlendExchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Sometimes we need a bit more information than what can be communicated with images and text. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your timeline doesn't show any keyframes. Are you sure you set them?

Comment: Yes I set them, you can see them in the Dope Sheet.

Answer (score -1):

I found out the problem. I had to change the setting in the render properties, light paths, to allow more transparency.